# Rotate array (list) in linear time and constant memory

Tags: python, algorithm, memory-management

How can I be sure that this Python algorithm uses constant memory?  A theoretical proof is OK.

A textbook* has this exercise: write an algorithm to "rotate" a list of *n* integers, in other words to shift the list values by *k* indices each.  The catch is that the algorithm should take linear time (proportional to *n*) and constant memory (the same amount for any *n*).  The rotation can be done with slicing:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> k = 3
>>> a = [i for i in range(n)]
>>> a = a[k:] + a[:k]
>>> a
[3, 4, 0, 1, 2]
```

I've verified that doubling *n* doubles the time taken, and so this algorithm takes linear time.  However, I'm not sure it takes constant memory.  I assume Python creates a new array that is the concatenation of the two slices, and then reassigns variable `a` to that array.  If so, then I think the memory used is proportional to *n*.  But how can I verify that?

The exercise also gives a hint that is cryptic to me: "Hint: Reverse three subarrays."  Why would there be a need to create three subarrays, and why reverse them?  Is that the trick to using constant memory?  I get that you could reverse the order of elements *0* through *k-1*, reverse the order of elements *k* through *n-1*, then reverse the order of all elements, but that seems like more operations, not less.

*The book is Introduction to Programming in Python, by Sedgewick, Wayne, and Dondero.  I'm teaching myself, not taking a course for credit.

Comment: It does not work in constant memory: here you will take *O(n)* extra memory for a moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick that the hint refers to is this:

To rotate a sequence of N elements left by M:

- reverse the whole sequence
- reverse the last M elements
- reverse the first N-M elements

done

e.g. left by 2:
1234567
->
7654321
->
7654312
->
3456712

Yes, this is the trick to using constant memory, because reversing a section of the array is easy to do in place.  I don't think there's a built in method for reversing subarrays, so you'd have to do something like:

```
i=0
j=n-m-1
while i<j:
    temp = a[i]
    a[i] = a[j]
    a[j] = temp
    i+=1
    j-=1
```

In python, this will probably be slower than the way you wrote it originally, but it is still linear time.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I think it only looks good on the paper... unfortunately implementing this using imported functions raises some problems. You can of course implement it by yourself but where is the fun in that?

Comment: @Yonif where I come from, implementing it yourself is exactly where the fun is :-)

Comment: I meant - this is not the "pythonic way" of doing that, as you said yourself, it will be slower :) You are more than welcome to help me and find a way of making this quick, maybe create a decorator class and over run `__len__()` (or something) so the reverse function will only reverse the first half!

Comment: To make sure I understand: your reversing method creates only 5 new variables regardless of *n*, whereas my slicing method creates new lists of total length *n*.  Thus your method uses constant memory and mine uses linear memory.

Comment: Using the `psutil` method `Process.memory_info` (stolen from Yonlif's answer) I actually see that the "triple reverse" method does use less memory than the slice method, but the amount of memory still doubles if *n* doubles.

Comment: The input array doesn't count

Comment: When I said "the amount of memory still doubles," I meant that the amount of extra memory added while executing the rotation doubles.  I got the memory at the beginning of the rotation algorithm (after the array was created) and then again at the end of the rotation algorithm, and took the difference.

Comment: With all the different garbage collection algorithms you may be using, there are many ways to get that measurement wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than performing swaps, you could carry a single element around and shift it into the next position:

```
def rotate(array,offset): # positive offset rotates left to right
    if not array or not offset: return
    index,value = 0,array[0]
    for _ in array:
        index = (index+offset)%len(array)
        value,array[index] = array[index],value
    
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
rotate(A,3)
print(A)

# [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Because of Python's ability to use negatives to index from the end of the array, the function will also work to rotate right to left by giving it a negative offset:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
rotate(A,-3)
print(A)

# [4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score -1):

I am aware that this solution returns an iterator and not a list but this might be good for other people looking for this question.

We can use `itertools` in order to perform the concatenation in "laziness"

```
import os
import psutil
import itertools


process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print(f"initial memory: {process.memory_info().rss}")

n = 10000
k = n // 2
a = [i for i in range(n)]

print(f"memory after creating the array: {process.memory_info().rss}")

res = itertools.chain(itertools.islice(a, k, None), itertools.islice(a, k))

print(f"memory after reordering the array: {process.memory_info().rss}")

for a in res:
    print(a)
print()

print(f"memory at the end: {process.memory_info().rss}")
```

The result will be:

> initial memory: 13025280
>   memory after creating the array: 13328384
>   memory after reordering the array: 13328384
>   5000
>   5001...
>   memory at the end: 13385728

With the original solution the memory will be higher...

Again, this result will bring back an iterator.

Fun fact: Printing all of the list at once will actually increase the processes memory due to the output buffer.

Comment: @AlainT. I'm aware that this is an iterator, I have stated it several times in my answer. There will not be a second allocation since `for` is using `next` (Also you can check the memory printings). Again I know I'm not rotating in place but this is a relevant answer for future users to look at.